# Connecting to cloud function running on emulator from android emulator in react native

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am building an application and using firebase for the backend. I used [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/) to use firebase in my application. I have developed a login cloud function

```
exports.login = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
   console.log("data", data);
   console.log("context", context);
   return "Login successful";
});
```

On running npm run serve in the functions folder I am getting these configurations in my console.
[Console output after running npm run serve inside functions folder for firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utgsZ.png)

Also I have added the following code to connect to the cloud function from my android emulator running the application.

```
import functions from "@react-native-firebase/functions"
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const handleLogin = () => {
        // console.log(email, password);
        functions()
            .useFunctionsEmulator("URL")
            .httpsCallable("login")({ email, password })
            .then((response) => {
                alert(response);
            });
    }
```

for URL I have tried "http://localhost:5001/" as it is the port on which the functions emulator is listening
[Port on which cloud functions is listening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FrrM.png). But on running the application I am getting this error
[Error on clicking login button in app console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjemv.png). I tried searching for the error but nothing relevant comes up. Any help will be appreciated.

These are my cloud functions that I have defined

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
   functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", { structuredData: true });
   response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});

exports.signup = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
   console.log("request", request);
   response.send("SignUp successfull");
});

exports.login = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
   console.log("data", data);
   console.log("context", context);
   return "SignIn successfull";
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to work it out finally

```
const handleLogin = async () => {
        functions().useFunctionsEmulator("http://localhost:5001")
        const response = await functions().httpsCallable("login")({ email, password });
        console.log("response", response);
    }
```

This is all the code required to successfully call cloud function locally inside an emulator from your running android emulator.